# RFID, Keyboard Wedge and Java

Tags: java, keyboard, rfid, wedge

There are loads of RFID tutorial on the com port but none on the usb.
There are descriptions of C# with the keyboard wedge but not for java.

I have a keyboard wedge,'think thats a c# term' it basically gives the id as keystrokes. I need to verify the keyboard input is coming from the rfid tag.

I got the reader from ebay, there is no configuration tool and no sdk or api. But works automatically as if its typing from the keyboard.

One suggestion I found on a c# answer was

*Currently I'm handling this by attaching to the KeyPress event and looking for a series of very fast key presses that contain the card swipe sentinel characters.*

looks hopeful but not sure how to do this

Answer (score 0):

I have done similar work in JavaScript to read magnet card swipes. You will need to measure the time between key press events. If the time is under a THRESHOLD (you might need to determine this experimentally), then its the wedge reader, so append the pressed key to your input string. Otherwise, its a human, so reset the state.

This is a rough example of how you might accomplish this:

```
private String input = "";
private long lastPress = 0;

public void onKeyPress(Event event) {
   if(lastPress - System.currentTimeInMillis() < THRESHOLD) {
     lastPress = System.currentTimeInMillis();
     input += event.getKey();
   } else {
     lastPress = 0;
     input = "";
   }
}
```

This is just a starting point. Your particular application may require additional conditions like checking for sentinels and what not to help determine if you are in a wedge read or not.